# Spring Boot защитить открытый API

Tags: spring, api, защита, boot

Ситуация простая. Есть сайт с формой обратной связи. Любой человек может написать там свой отзыв. Далее происходит запрос POST на некий URL типа https://blabla.com/api/v1/feedback Далее полученная инфа сохраняется в БД и отправляется почтой админу сайта.
Получается, что любой человек может написать простой цикл и отправлять сообщение по сотне раз в секунду.
Вопрос простой. Как мне обеспечить отправку формы обратной связи и защититься от "плохих" ребят?
Как вы поняли API создано на Spring Boot

Comment: Сделать банальный rate limit по IP-адресу?

Comment: Хорошая идея. Ну допустим делаем лимит и получаем запись в БД и отправленное письмо в цикле, просто не каждую секунду, а раз в минуту.

Comment: Рейт-лимиты, экспоненциальный таймаут между запросами, капча/челлендж, блоклисты адресов, клаудфлара.

Comment: Ого, накидал идей, спасибо.

Comment: @МихаилСтепнов почему именно раз в минуту-то, я на одном сайте делал три раза в сутки, например)

Comment: @andreymal Бывает ситуация, когда у большой группы людей один внешний IP адрес. Получается, что один оставит отзыв, а второй уже не сможет. Я просто пытаюсь не изобретать велосипед, а найти какой-то рабочий, устоявшийся, проверенный годами и сотнями людей способ. Но чем больше погружаюсь в вопрос, тем больше понимаю, что все делают как ни попадя. Нет какого-то надежного стандарта, у всех по-разному.

Comment: @МихаилСтепнов ну тогда только капча